# Errors running JavaFX .jar file on Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, javafx

I'm trying to make the JavaFX application I made on Windows work for Ubuntu. I've made the .jar file and it works fine on Windows 10, but won't work on Ubuntu. Whether I double click it from the desktop (with running as executable enabled) or run it from the terminal, I keep getting these errors:

`javac myApp.jar` or `javac myApp`

```
error: Class names, 'myApp.jar', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
```

`javac -cp myApp.jar` or `javac -cp myApp`

```
javac: no source files
```

This is the error I get on running java -jar myApp.jar:

```
Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javarx/application/Application
```

This is my MANIFEST file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: 
Implementation-Version: 
Permissions: sandbox
JavaFX-Version: 8.0
Class-Path: 
Created-By: JavaFX Packager
Implementation-Vendor: 
Main-Class: Main
```

I have installed Java using the `apt install default-jre` command. I've also installed JavaFX.

I think it might be some issue with where the application tries to get its JavaFX library from, but I'm not sure whether this is it or how I'd fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently in order to get JavaFX with your Java distribution, you have to download it form Oracle instead of the regular openjdk-8-jre. I got my solution from this [website](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/07/31/install-oracle-java-8-9-ubuntu-16-04-linux-mint-18/). Thanks to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 0):

[`default-jre`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/default-jre) package will install Open JDK 11 in Ubuntu Bionic. [Java 11 removed JavaFX from the default distribution](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/the-future-of-javafx-and-other-java-client-roadmap-updates). This binaries are now shipped separately outside of the JDK, you can get them [from Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-base/11).

Either downgrade to a lower version of JRE/JDK or repackage the application to include the JavaFX binaries so it can work with Java 11.